# Cant set Android Actionbar Background correctly

Tags: android, styles, android-actionbar

**The Problem**
When im setting the ActionBar Background Color the Bar looks like this:

i cant upload Images here so here is the File:
[Android ActionBar Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sth52.jpg)

**My values/styles File**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<!--
    Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
    by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.

-->
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <!--
        Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
        res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
        backward-compatibility can go here.

    -->
</style>

<!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBarTheme</item>
</style>

<!-- Action Bar theme -->
<style name="ActionBarTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/actionbar</item>
    <item name="background">@drawable/actionbar</item>
</style>

<style name="FullscreenTheme" parent="android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@null</item>
    <item name="metaButtonBarStyle">@style/ButtonBar</item>
    <item name="metaButtonBarButtonStyle">@style/ButtonBarButton</item>
</style>

<style name="ButtonBar">
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">2dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingTop">5dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">2dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingBottom">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:background">@android:drawable/bottom_bar</item>
</style>

<style name="ButtonBarButton" />

</resources>
```

**My Manifest File**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.application"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/symbol"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.application.Main"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/FullscreenTheme" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.application.Settings"
        android:parentActivityName="com.application.Main"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/ActionBarTheme">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.application.Main" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.application.DateList"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/FullscreenTheme" >
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

**I also try this but the same happened**

```
ColorDrawable draw = new ColorDrawable(R.color.grey);
getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(draw);
```

**My Color Drawable**

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <solid
        android:color="@color/grey" />

</shape>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(draw);
```

should be, in your case

```
getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(getResources.getDrawable(R.drawable.your_drawable_name);
```

The Constructor of `ColorDrawable` takes the int that represent the color, not the `id` of the color. Use instenad

`ColorDrawable draw = new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(R.color.grey));`

Edit:

about the style.xml, you need both the item with and without the android prefix:

```
<!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
   <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBarTheme</item>  
   <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBarTheme</item>
</style>
```

Lint is probably going to complain about it, because of the minSDK value. if it does you can add `tools:ignore="NewApi"` to the item with the `android:` prefix. For instance:

```
 <item name="android:actionBarStyle" tools:ignore="NewApi">@style/ActionBarTheme</item>
```

Comment: I agree you code works, but why would a `ColorDrawable` not work as a `Drawable` in that case?

Comment: for the same reasons. You should use getResources().getColor(R.color.grey). I edited my answer

Comment: I got it with "The Constructor of ColorDrawable takes the int that represent the color, not the id of the color." Thank you

Comment: Thank you! That helped me. But im a little bit confused, why it wont work with the style.xml ?

Comment: which version of android has the deveice where you are testing it?

Comment: Can you please have a look at my question please? https://stackoverflow.com/q/57115274/1080355