# Gradle build error style attributes not found

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I was trying to roll my project back to a previous version by checking the git out from GitHub, but I think I did it in a wrong way. I just removed the local project and checked out the git address on android studio. However, the gradle can't build and shows this message:

I navigate to the line that is saying style attr not found, and select find usage, but it says no usage in this project. I also tried removed the twitter tool kits and load it again, and load an older verision, both still have this issue. How to fix this?
[image: gradle build wrong]

The project is build with android studio 3.0 canary from beginning. this is the app gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "..."
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 3
        versionName "beta1"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.0.0'
    compile 'com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:3.1.0'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.7.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.8.1'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.7.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.0.0'
}
```

And another build file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-alpha9'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: Can you try a `Build/Clean Project` and then a `File/Invalidate Caches Restart`? The reason for this is if there are merged / generated XML and an external update from git then the generated XML may be referencing classes from upstream

Comment: Yes in this roll back version some xml files are gone and generates no reference error. I guess I selected wrong base branch when merging. Many thanks!@DavidRawson

Comment: this is really stupid...and im sure most people wouldn't run into this..but I had a typo in my attr name so when i later spelled it correctly it wasn't found.. ‍♀️

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is a problem with themes and styles. Probably one of your libraries is expecting that style to be available and it's not finding it. See here [Cant set Android Actionbar Background correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23358751/cant-set-android-actionbar-background-correctly) as a guide on how to fill in that particular attribute that may work for you.

This resource seems to have been introduced in 2013 according to google's diffs here https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/base/+/f5215ae4712f468568b58c20baadd14b769c10c4%5E!/

Changing your themes.xml followed by using it from the manifest, or changing styles.xml can potentially cause those side effects if not done properly.

Comment: Yes, it's a theme problem. I had a unused style referenced a private color attr from a library. Removed the style and it works well now. Many thanks!

Comment: @Fabio Can you please have a look at my question related to this? https://stackoverflow.com/q/57115274/1080355

Answer (score 4):

Adding Preference Support Library v7 dependency to Gradle solved a problem for me. It supports missed attributes for @style/PreferenceThemeOverlay.

Put the following line to your build.gradle module:

`com.android.support:preference-v7:27.1.1`

Comment: that helped me, I used other version though

Comment: Using AndroidX

// Java language implementation
implementation "androidx.preference:preference:1.1.1"
// Kotlin
implementation "androidx.preference:preference-ktx:1.1.1"

Answer (score 2):

**2020 UPDATE**: Unfortunately, it seems they haven't fix this issue yet, so the solution is to simple downgrade gradle version. For example, change it from:

`classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.3'`

to

`classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.1'`

and it will work.

Comment: I am facing similar issue when upgrading to gradle version 4.1.1 from 3.6.0. For me, error is — AAPT: error: style attribute 'android:attr/contextPopupMenuStyle' not found. I would think we can do sth to fix it rather than downgrading (or not updating in my case) to fix this issue, no?

Answer (score 0):

If you use a theme style with parent="android:Theme.DeviceDefault", you should use

```
<item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
```

instead of

```
<item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
```

Or change the theme style from "android:Theme.DeviceDefault" to "Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar", it also may resolves some other style problems.

Answer (score 0):

The error "AAPT: error: attribute android:style not found" usually occurs when the style or theme you are trying to use is not compatible with the version of Android that you are compiling against.

To use the style in a Material Design component, you need to make sure that you are using the correct version of the Material Design support library that is compatible with the version of Android that you are compiling against.

Make sure that you have added the correct dependency for the Material Design support library in your build.gradle file, depending on the version of Android that you are compiling against. For example, if you are compiling for API 28, add the Material Design support library dependency for version 28:

```
dependencies {
   implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'
}
```

Also, make sure that you are not setting the android:style attribute on the button. Instead, you should set the style using the style attribute:

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
...
style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton"
.../>
```

I hope this helps to resolve the error that you're facing.