# Gradle build error styles attributes not found

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, styles

I was try to upgrade android studio 2.3 to 3.0 but the gradle can't build and shows this message:
Probably one of your libraries is expecting that style to be available and it's not finding it

please help me to fix this error.

[screenshot of the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Nose.png)

this is the build.gradle of the project

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'


repositories {
    maven {
        url 'https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/'
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.skills.inuk"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "0.3.2"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true //important
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }

    buildTypes {

        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }

    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'LICENSE.txt'
    }
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    // compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha7'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.1'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.6.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
    compile 'com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:3+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.4.2'
    compile 'com.makeramen:roundedimageview:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.github.curioustechizen.android-ago:library:1.3.4'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.5'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha7'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:26.0.1'
    compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.6.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Thx for your reponses guys, i founded the probleme , this happening because :

Consider if you incorrectly include the symbol when accessing a resource from the android namespace, as shown below:

```
<!-- When referencing resources from the 'android' namespace, omit the '@' symbol. -->
<item name="@android:windowEnterAnimation"/>
```

Comment: have you tried this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/45580069/2035645

Comment: Yes i tried this solution and didn't works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to your `gradle.properties` write the below code and Sync your project

```
android.enableAapt2=false
```

And remove `@` symbol because from `Android Studio 3.0`

> When referencing resources from the 'android' namespace, omit the '@' symbol.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to use `?android:attr/background` and `?android:attr/textColor` instead of `@android:attr/background` and `@android:attr/textColor`

Comment: WARNING: The following project options are deprecated and have been removed: 
android.enableAapt2 
This property has no effect, AAPT2 is now always used.

Answer (score 0):

android:style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"

remove android, it should be

style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"